# WooCommerce custom fields comma separated on condition

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a book store on WooCommerce and I have created custom fields for book product:

1. Author
2. Publisher
3. Year

I want to make products page look like:

```
/// Image /// (/br)
PROD.NAME(/br)
Author(/br)
Publisher, Year(/br)
Price and button Add to cart below
```

I use this code for displaying "Publisher, Year":

```
<?php 
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author', true); 
    echo ', ';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'year', true); 
?>
```

And all is fine, BUT if i had no Publisher set in custom field I got ", Year" string. And that's my question - is it possible to not show a comma, if first or second field is not being set and how to do this?

---

The problem is solved but may be some more extra - I think it is some kind of similar but I cant get it:

at the Single Product page it should be the list:

1. Author: *author*
2. Publisher: *publisher*
3. Year: *year*

and same logic: if there is a field data it should show whole string and if not just dont show anything. For now I got:

1. Author: James Krooker
2. Publisher: NS Doorgates
3. Year:

(in this scenario I got no Year set but the string "Year: *nothing* " appears.

Comment: Thanks for formatting guys, I appreciate it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much into wordpress, but you can do something like:

```
<?php
  //I assume you meant publisher, not author
  $publisher = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'publisher', true);
  $year = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'year', true);
  if (($publisher == '') || ($year == ''))
     echo $publisher.$year;
  else
     echo $publisher.', '.$year;
?>
```

As I said, I'm not much into wordpress and I use `==` operator.
You can make it more strict if you know what is returned by `get_post_meta()` on unset field (this can be either NULL, empty string, FALSE...) and use `===` operator.

---

When it comes to your second question... it shouldn't be a problem...

```
<?php
   //assign variables with get_post_meat as before...

   if ($author != '')
       echo 'Author: '.$author;
   if ($publisher != '')
       echo 'Publisher: '.$publisher;
   if ($year != '')
      echo 'Year: '.$year;
?>
```

I suggest you read [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), especially section about [flow control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).